# Which polymorphism types are supported in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types, polymorphism

Reading the Wikipedia definition of [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)), I come with a question:

Which polymorphism types are supported in Haskell and which are not?

Looks like Wikipedia do not contain a description for some polymorphism types like [Levity Polymorphism](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/levity-1.pdf) which is new for me and supported in Haskell.

I wondering to have an extended list of [Haskell Polymorphism](https://wiki.haskell.org/Polymorphism) followed with examples to explore deeply.

Looks like the main two are:

- Parametric polymorphism
- Ad-hoc polymorphism

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for a Big List of things, rather than something where a single answer could be valid, or a concrete problem to solve.

Comment: @JosephSible I respect your vote. But you didn't convince me about how big the list of things to explain.

Comment: The reasons why I am asking are two: To learn Haskell deeply. Also, I expect a similar question on tech interview.

Comment: I upvoted because there's probably a fairly short, definite answer to this question, at least for a specific version of GHC. Polymorphism in general is a pretty abstract concept, but there must be a finite list of language features implemented in GHC that enable some form of polymorphism, and that's a concrete question of fact.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are at least four things that can count as polymorphism in current Haskell:

- Parametric polymorphism. (Also [kind polymorphism](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#kind-polymorphism), polymorphism in the kinds instead of the types. Which I guess is parametric polymorphism one level above, so I'm not counting it as a separate entry.)
- Ad-hoc polymorphism, the one enabled by typeclasses. Introduced in the [How to make ad-hoc polymorphism less ad hoc](https://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/karkare/courses/2010/cs653/Papers/ad-hoc-polymorphism.pdf) paper.
- [Structural polymorphism](https://www.andres-loeh.de/Koke2005.pdf). This is the one enabled by [generics](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/GHC-Generics.html). A function can work over multiple data types that have different number of fields and constructors. For example, a generic equality function for records.
- [Levity polymorphism](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lSJwXZ7vWBw). Polymorphism over calling conventions / runtime representations of types. Described in the [Levity Polymorphism](https://cs.brynmawr.edu/~rae/papers/2017/levity/levity-extended.pdf) paper.

There are two more types of polymorphism that *might* be introduced in future versions of Haskell:

- Matchability polymorphism. Would allow higher-order type families to work with both type constructors and type families as arguments. Described in the paper [Higher-order Type-level Programming in Haskell](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2019/03/ho-haskell.pdf).
- Multiplicity polymorphism. Would allow higher-order functions to work with both normal functions and linear functions as arguments. Described in the paper [Linear Haskell Practical Linearity in a Higher-Order Polymorphic Language](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.09756.pdf).

One might ask, why this whole panoply of polymorphisms? There seems to exist an overall design principle in Haskell that, whenever some challenge could be solved with either subtyping *or* polymorphism, *polymorphism should be preferred*.

For example, from the levity polymorphism paper:

> We can now present the main idea of the paper: replace sub-kinding
>   with kind polymorphism.

From the paper introducing matchability polymorphism:

> At first you might think that we need subtyping, but instead we turn to polymorphism

From the linear Haskell paper:

> The lack of subtyping is a deliberate choice in our design

Simon Peyton Jones himself makes the point at [47:00](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t0mhvd3-60Y&feature=youtu.be&t=2820) in [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t0mhvd3-60Y).

> Whenever you want to use subtyping, use polymorphism instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can I say that the higher-rank polymorphism a special case of parametric polymorphism?

Comment: One might argue that subtyping is another kind of polymorphism. Subtyping is in fact sort of supported in Haskell with existential types, but should be used with extreme caution indeed.

Comment: @mkUltra higher-rank polymorphism allows the use of parametric/ad-hoc polymorphism inside functions passed as arguments to higher-order-functions, something that is not enabled by default https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-RankNTypes https://kseo.github.io/posts/2016-12-27-higher-rank-polymorphism.html it also enables higher-rank-kinds  https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#higher-rank-kinds